# Scaling SVG help needed

Tags: html, css, scaling

I am struggling a bit with the following HTML/CSS in order to scale all SVG's with the same height/width.
I created a simple set-up but I don't know what to do..

When I open the images in the browser they are all scaled (fullscreen) and looking all the same by its dimensions. But when using this in HTML I don't get nice results.

Any tips are really appreciated..

```css
img {
 height: auto;
 width: 75%;
  
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <title>Debugging</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- COURSES -->
  <div class="container courses-container">
    <div class="row ">
      <!--COURSE 1-->
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-2 course-item">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/aa.svg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Монстр один</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Виж Повече</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--COURSE 2-->
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4    col-xl-2 course-item">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/USStates.svg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Монстр два</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Виж Повече</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--COURSE 3-->
      <div class="col-6 col-md-4    col-xl-2 course-item">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/Steps.svg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Китара</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Виж Повече</a>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they don't have the same size, see their viewbox,
just change your css to

```css
img {
  height: 183px;
  width : auto;
}
```